# What's the mechanism of Inner Load Balancing along with docker swarm v1.12

Tags: nginx, docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

Docker Swarm mode achieves Inner Load Balancing, and as far as I know, nginx is called hard load balancing, zookeeper is kinda soft load balancing.

So what's the mechanism of the Inner Load Balancing coming along with Docker v1.12?

Does it embed a nginx inside or similar methods like zookeeper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Inner" load balancing? Not exactly.
[Commit ea4fef2](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/ea4fef2d875de39044ca7570c35365b75086e8a5) documents it ([`docs/swarm/key-concepts.md`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/ea4fef2d875de39044ca7570c35365b75086e8a5/docs/swarm/key-concepts.md#load-balancing)) as

> Swarm uses **ingress load balancing** to expose the services you want to make available externally to the Swarm.
>   Swarm can automatically assign the service a `PublishedPort` or you can configure a `PublishedPort` for the service in the 30000-32767 range.
>   External components, such as cloud load balancers, can access the service on the `PublishedPort` of any node in the cluster, even if the node is not currently running the service.
>
> Swarm has an internal DNS component that automatically assigns each service in the Swarm DNS entry.
>   Swarm uses **internal load balancing** to distribute requests among services within the cluster based upon the services' DNS name.

Right now (docker 1.12 August 2016), that inner load balancing does not work consistently: [issue 25325](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25325)

> ```
> ➜  ~ time curl http://10.218.3.5:30000
> I'm 272dd0310a95
> curl http://10.218.3.5:30000  0.01s user 0.01s system 6% cpu 0.217 total
> ➜  ~ time curl http://10.218.3.5:30000
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.218.3.5 port 30000: Operation timed out
> ```

And [swarmkit issue 1077](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1077) illustrates there is no plan yet to

> provide capabilities for session stickiness (cookie-based etc.) in this router mesh.
>   As awesome as it would be, not all apps are stateless, and we need to route users to the proper container in certain cases

Because:

> since we do load balancing at L3/L4 it cannot be bases on things like session cookie.
>   The best that can be done is to have Source IP based stickiness.

And source IP is not always good enough:

> That wouldn't work for our case.
>   We would have an upstream load balancer (F5) which would make traffic appear to come from a single IP, the "SNAT pool" IP on the F5 since it is a full proxy.
>   Effectively, Source IP based stickiness would cause all requests to go to one container since all the source IPs would come from the same address.

So the internal load balancer remains quite "basic":

> The main issue with adding "session stickyness" is that there are a hundred ways to do it.
>   It is also an L7 feature, whereas **our load balancing operates at L3/4**.
>
> There are two high-level paths here:
>
> - Monitor events coming from the docker API to modify F5 state to route directly task slots.
> - Integrate with libnetwork and have the loadbalancer operate as an L7 LB would if it were running directly in the swarm.

The conclusion for now is:

> If you want to handle all aspects of load balancing and not use IPVS, you can disable it by running services in DNSRR mode. You can run any load balancer inside of swarm to do load balancing, bypassing the service VIP and populate backends with the DNSRR entries.

That is why the latest release 1.12 has, with [PR 827](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/pull/827), added support for DNSRR mode and disabling ingress.